# determining batch size and epoch size of neural network

Tags: neural-network

what should be my batch size and epoch size for 2 layer neural network if I am working with 1700 data?
I also want to know about neurons.how to determine the number??

Comment: Why closed? Cant people ask questions here what they dont know about? or is this place only for phd holders?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on many things. Batch size is how many instances will be accepted as input by your model, in order to make a complete forward pass and propagate the appropriate gradients backwards. Having a batch size too small could lead to gradients that derived from a batch which is not representative of the data distribution, thus these gradients could be harmful. Having a large batch size in a huge dataset could lead to memory issues. Having said that, use 128.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you pleas tell about epoch size as well?

Comment: Yeah! 1 epoch is a forward pass of every datapoint in your set. You have 1700 data and that means 13 forward passes of 128 batch size (128 instances) and one more pass of the 36 remaining data (1700 - 128 * 13). Remember gradients change after each batch. You do not need many parameters in your network because you do not have many examples to train on, so just run your network for 40 epochs and evaluate it on your train data and then on your validation data. If it performs very well on your train data but not that well on validation data, then reduce the number of epochs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your well explained answer. Really appreciate it.when you are at it can you please tell about the neuron umber well? how I determine the number of neuron on each layer?

Comment: Yeah! You should have 2 layers for your network. Your first layer should have 10 neurons and your second layer should have 18 neurons. Use relu as your activation function for the hidden layers.

Comment: Why 10 ad 18 may I ask?

Comment: There is no general rule. You should experiment with multiple values since it will not take much time for your network to train. The reason 2 layers were proposed is to make sure your network can simulate non-linear phenomena and the numbers 10 and 18 can change, however I proposed these two because given that you have 1700 instances only (and thats everything you told us about your problem) it would be wise to avoid huge networks with many parameters. 10 and 18 have relatively low parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much.Can you please tell how to increase accuracy? I am working with time series data here and getting accuracy around 70%

Comment: Okay so you're saying you are trying to classify timeseries. 70% sounds very high. Have you splitted into train and test? There are infinite thing that you have not told us so I cannot help you any more. However, you may play around with your network's parameters, do not forget to Normalize your data before passing into the network.

Comment: it is a regression problem and trying to predict air pollution.splited it in train validation and test.and normalized as well. Dont know i I am missing anything.

Comment: You are missing that you mentioned accuracy in a regression problem. Use RMSE to evaluate your models. Your models may be performing well and you don't even know it. If you achieve low RMSE for your train data but high for test data then make a simpler model.

Comment: Yeah I told you the R squared score which is 0.732.

Comment: You named it accuracy, very misleading. Anyway I cannot help you I know nothing more of the task. Just try doing the things I mentioned. R squared 0.732 is actually very good. Print the predictions and you may notice that they are close to the actual values.

Comment: Sorry for that as I have been self learning from various tutorials and they mentioned it accuracy. Dont now what else method is there to get the accuracy. But Thanks a lot for all your response.really helped.